# promise execution with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, hapi.js

I have a following promise function

```
function run(args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { //logic });
}
```

I want to pass an argument to the promise function `run` and on the returned value I want to have some condition, if it satisfies I want to pass one set of argument to the promise and if it fails the other set of result and on the basis of the above promise result a last promise with the consolidated values from the above promise as argument.

```
run(a)
    .then(()  =>{
    if (condition) {
        run(b)
            .then(() => {
                return something
            })
    }
    else
        run(c)
            .then(() => {
                return something
            })
})
.then(rows => {
    use the something returned
})
```

Something like above
Is it possible. Also what if both the condition is not satisfied how to handle the error ?

or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: so you want promise chaining?

Comment: `return run(b).`, `return run(c).` ?

Comment: the final .then depends on the result from run(a) and either one of run(b) or run(c)

Comment: and yeah I want promise chaning, but the promise should execute if the condition is satisfied

Comment: `run(a).then(() => run(condition ? b : c)).then(() => something).then(rows => { … })`. Or are those different somethings in the conditional branches?

Answer (score 0):

That's two questions, really, but oh well...

### Conditionally returning one of two different promises

Basically, in the first `.then()`, you have to return a promise. You do so by adding `return` before `run(b)` and `run(c)`. This will make the second `.then()` pick up the value of `something`.

```
.then(() => {
    if (condition) {
        return run(b).then(() => {
            return something;
        });
    } else {
        return run(c).then(() => {
            return something;
        });
    }
})
```

### Error throwing and handling

Your scenario is a simple `if`-`else`. One of the two will always be fulfilled, so there is no "if no condition is satisfied". However, let us assume you have two conditions instead, and one must be satisfied in order for the entire thing to be considered fulfilled. All you need to do is throw an `Error`:

```
.then(() => {
    if (condition1) {
        return run(b);
    } else if (condition2) {
        return run(c);
    }
    throw new Error("Neither condition was true.");
})
.then(rows => {
    // use the something returned
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The thrown `Error` object will be received as argument `err` by the final `.catch()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of different ways to handle this, but here is one.

```
then((data) => {
    let nextCall;

     if ( data === "Something") {
          nextCall = somePromiseFunction(data);
     } else {
          nextCall = someOtherPromiseFunction(data);
     }

     return nextCall;
})
.then((data) => { ... })
```